# shouldStartLoadWithRequest and address data detectors, how to get the address?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am using a UIWebView with address (postal address) data detector enabled (iOS 4,5 or 6). When being called in shouldStartLoadWithRequest after tapping on an address which has been detected, I get a URL in the form: x-apple-data-detectors//4
How can I extract the address from this? Also, calling UIApplication's openURL with such a URL doens't work (nothing happens).